# Excel 2010 - Extracting Clock In Entries that Have no Clock Out

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Thanks in advance for any help on this situation.

I have an Excel sheet that is raw data from a time clock system. This data has the following columns:

```
A: Date/Time of Entry
B: Purpose of Entry (Either Clock IN or Clock OUT)
C: Unique ID of employee clocking in or out
```

For every clock in that's associated with a Unique ID, there MUST be a clock out also on the same day for that unique ID. I need to extract all entries that have no clock outs associated with a clock in for that day.

Comment: So, what's your question exactly? What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I am looking for a way to easily extract such data without manually having to do it. I have a spreadsheet with over a years worth of these entries that I would need to comb through. My Excel is very rusty, I can't seem to figure out how to get this done at all.

Answer (score 0):

Rough code.

Get the number of rows (called intROWEND)

```
for intCOUNTER = 1 to intROWEND - 1 do

  get date for row(intCOUNTER)

  get UNIQUEID for row(intCOUNTER)

  booleanCLOCKEDOUT = False

  for intCOUNTER2 = intCOUNTER + 1 to intROWEND

    if (date(row(intCOUNTER) = date(row(intCOUNTER2)) and (UNIQUEID(intCOUNTER) = (UNIQUEID(intCOUNTER2)) then booleanCLOCKEDOUT = True

  next

  if booleanCLOCKEDOUT = False then output date and UNIQUEID

next
```

Comment: Wow thank you. I am assuming I have to name each column to fit within this code?

Comment: I am ashamed to say I wouldnt know how to set this up. I enabled the developer tab and inserted this VB code in VB but don't I have to identify the variables Date, UniqueID and Clockedout?

Answer (score 0):

This array formula counts the number of OUTs for the same employee in the same day for every IN. Enter as an array formula by confirming with ctrl+shift+enter.

`=IF(B1="IN",SUM(IF(INT(A$1:A$6)=INT(A1),IF(B$1:B$6="OUT",IF(C$1:C$6=C1,1),0),0)),"")`

If you see a clock in with a 0 it means there are no associated clock outs in the same day.

Comment: I don't understand how or where to use this formula.

Comment: @ChrisM What exactly is giving you trouble? Using this formula is a relatively simple matter of updating the cell references to match your data and autofilling down.